# Reinstall Let's Encrypt

Tags: lets-encrypt

I have Ubuntu 18.04 with Nginx (for website) and Let's Encrypt. 
It works as it should, but I have a question. Some months ago I migrated from Apache to Nginx. Now I noticed that Let's Encrypt isn't in "optimal condition" :-)
It works properly, but in /etc/letsencrypt/renewal conf file, I can see:

```
authenticator=apache
installer=apache
```

Beside that, there is only options-ssl-apache.conf in /etc/letsencrypt folder. In my opinion, this isn't optimal configuration, even if it looks ok. 
Any idea how to solve the situation? Remove Let's Encrypt, delete certs and install it again with only Nginx support. BTW - Apache isn't installed any more.

Comment: What "letsencrypt" did you install exactly? certbot package?

Comment: Yes, the certbot package.

Answer (score 1):

You should reinstall with certbort nginx.

You can use this tutorial

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @KaungThant - this was the same as I thought. Tnx.